# How to handle dramatic orientation changes in iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, orientation

I have used auto sizing and auto lay outs before to handle minor changes before(to make a view stick to the right or positioning in center or expanding and shrinking view to fit in screen) But now I have a screen like this in landscape :

```
---------------  ----
|             |  | B|
|      A      |  ----
|             |  | C|
|             |  ----
---------------
```

And in portrait

```
---------------
|             |
|      A      |
|             |
---------------
---- -----
| B| | C |
---- ----
```

In this kind of situation what would be the ideal way to handle orientation changes ?
Should I use different storyboards for landscape and portrait ? If so would I loose any data which user might have entered in portrait when orientation changed landscape ?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targeting? iOS 8 introduces the notion of size classes (part of "adaptive UI"), the usage of which I would recommend. Xcode 6 features very useful addition to the Interface Builder to design these size classes. See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW30).